# Wordpress Site Logo

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a WordPress site and the logo when your on the site is fine. But! when I search for the site in the address bar it shows an old logo that I don't want on there anymore until I'm finished typing it out. Does anybody know how to change this?

```
                                          Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the browser cache? Try opening your page from incognito window, please. If that problem occurs again let me know.

Comment: Hey Kristel. Thank you for answering. I did try both of those and it's still showing the old logo. I appreciate you helping. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Hm , have you deleted the old logo out of the media ? I mean the favicon you had before the current one. If that doesn t work out, go to your Dashboard Wordpress,  go to Appearance > Editor > header.php. Put this code after the <title> label, and in the href, write the path of the icon 

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/(nameoficon)" type="image/x-icon" />